# Tkinter button with captured video in the same window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, video-capture

I want to make a single GUI with button, and displaying the video inside the same window when i click this button. In my code bellow, there is a window of tkinter appeared with the button, and when I click that button, it display a video capture in (another window), I want this captured video appeared in the same window that contains the button. can anyone please help me to edit this code with all my thanks.

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk

def cap_vid():

    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while (True):

        ret, frame = vid.read()

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break


root = tk.Tk()

video_label = tk.Label()
video_label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")


my_button = tk.Button(text="Click Me", command=cap_vid)
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are examples on this subject can be found if you search the internet or StackOverflow.

Comment: I searched about examples, but I can't found anything do what I want, all examples like my above code where the captured video window separated from the stkinter window that contain buttons. Can you please help me with example?

Comment: I can find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358293/python-3-x-tkinter-integrating-frames-from-opencv-cv2-into-tkinter-window) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670461/read-an-image-with-opencv-and-display-it-with-tkinter).