# How to display an image from OpenCV in a Tkinter interface?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to continuously display and replace an image in a Tkinter interface taken from OpenCV's VideoCapture. However, I am getting the following error that I think is a result of improper formatting of the image numpy array:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

How can I reformat it to all it to display properly? Below is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

main = tk.Tk()
main.title("Hole Pattern Recognition")
main.geometry("300x300")

frame = tk.Frame(main)
frame.pack()

def startScan():
    global main, frame
    #begins utilizing webcam for scan
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while(True):
        ret,img = cap.read()
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        panel = tk.Label(main, image = img)
        panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
        ch = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if ch == ord('q'):
            break
        
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    
    
startButton = tk.Button(frame, 
                   text="Start Scan", 
                   fg="blue",
                   command=startScan)

startButton.pack(side=tk.TOP)
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you please include you `import` statements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670461/read-an-image-with-opencv-and-display-it-with-tkinter I think this will work for you.

Comment: First you need to use `PIL.Image.fromarray()` to convert the captured image to format supported by tkinter.  Second better not use while loop in main thread as it will block the tkinter mainloop.

Comment: @Ralubrusto I just updated the import statements

Comment: @acw1668 how can I loop through and constantly show a new image then?

Comment: Use `after()` instead of the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use `PIL.Image.fromarray()` to convert the captured image to format supported by tkinter.

Second better not use while loop in main thread as it will block the tkinter mainloop.  Use `after()` instead.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

cap = None

main = tk.Tk()
main.title('Hole Pattern Recognition')
#main.geometry('300x300')

frame = tk.Frame(main)
frame.pack()

def startScan():
    global cap

    def scan():
        ret, img = cap.read()
        if ret:
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = Image.fromarray(img)
            tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            panel.config(image=tkimg)
            panel.tkimg = tkimg # save a reference to the image to avoid garbage collection
        panel.after(25, scan) # change 25 to other value to adjust FPS

    if cap is None:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        scan() # start the capture loop
    else:
        print('capture already started')

startButton = tk.Button(frame, text='Start Scan', fg='blue', command=startScan)
startButton.pack()

panel = tk.Label(main)
panel.pack()

main.mainloop()

if cap:
    cap.release()
```